# metaio SDK6 doesn't work on Android 4.0

Tags: android, metaio

I have upgraded metaio SDK to version 6, and experiencing issue in Android device having OS version 4.0. I'm getting the following error.

```
Could not find class 'com.metaio.sdk.ARViewActivity$1', referenced from method com.metaio.sdk.ARViewActivity.onCreate
 Could not find class 'android.hardware.display.DisplayManager', referenced from method com.metaio.sdk.ARViewActivity.onPause
 Could not find class 'android.hardware.display.DisplayManager', referenced from method com.metaio.sdk.ARViewActivity.onResume
```

I couldn't find the reason for this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was a change in the permissions

from

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope"
    android:required="false" />
```

to this

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope"
    android:required="true" />
```

Comment: even though, I made these changes, I got the same error, and scan doesn't work.